# regex pattern - what is ((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+)) and (?![.\n])

Tags: regex

can someone kindly explain this regex pattern to me?

under

```
(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

what exactly is

```
((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))
```

&

```
(?![.\n])
```

thank you

Comment: (?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]) means a-z lowercase and uppercase... whhat about the rest?

Comment: These are lookahead assertions. See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Paste your regex in there and it will explain it to you: http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are all lookahead assertions (positive and negative) that are making sure the following text respects some rules without actually capturing the text.

```
               # assert that
(?=^.{8,}$)    # there are at least 8 characters
(              # and
  (?=.*\d)       # there is at least a digit
  |              # or
  (?=.*\W+)      # there is one or more "non word" characters (\W is equivalent to [^a-zA-Z0-9_])
)              # and
(?![.\n])      # there is no . or newline and
(?=.*[A-Z])    # there is at least an upper case letter and
(?=.*[a-z]).*$ # there is at least a lower case letter
.*$            # in a string of any characters
```

`(?! ... )` is the syntax for a negative lookahead (match if there is no ...), `(?= ... )` is for a positive lookahead (match if there is ...). This looks a lot like password validation!

Answer (score 2):

1. String matches to end of line
2. At least 8 characters in length
3. At least one digit or non-word character exists (*not* a-zA-Z0-9_)
4. No new line found (ie. string is one line long)
5. At least one uppercase letter exists
6. At least one lowercase letter exists

This seems to be a RegEx for validating a password.