# What ( ? = ) in the expression?

Tags: javascript, nsregularexpression

I'm looking at the following regular expression and wondering if it is:

- testing for last of input?
- testing for something else?

```
(? =. *\d)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regex pattern - what is ((?=.\*\d)|(?=.\*\W+)) and (?!\[.\n\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632713/regex-pattern-what-is-d-w-and-n)

Answer (score 0):

It means lookahead assertion

A lookahead assertion has the form (?= test) and can appear anywhere in a regular expression. MATLAB® looks ahead of the current location in the text for the test condition. If MATLAB matches the test condition, it continues processing the rest of the expression to find a match.

NOTE: The ? character may also be used as a quantifier.

[Regular expression syntax cheatsheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet)

This page provides an overall cheat sheet of all the capabilities of RegExp syntax by aggregating the content of the articles in the RegExp guide. If you need more information on a specific topic, please follow the link on the corresponding heading to access the full Info